# How to use predict function with text categories?

Tags: r, classification, knn, predict

I have been having trouble with the predict function underestimating (or overestimating) the predictions for new text category (or its class if they sport...health....politcs)

Firstly I import a tdm matrix of my corpus then split my data training / test to use in my model with knn algorithm.

And it works fine.

Now I need to import new text unknown category to predict it but I did not how to do that.

I don't how to use predict function

The error is

```
ff<-predict(knn.pred,PathFilename)
```

> Error in UseMethod("predict") :
>     no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "factor"

```
# Text mining: Corpus and Document Term Matrix
library(tm)
# KNN model
library(class) 
# Stemming words
library(SnowballC)
# CrossTable
library('gmodels')
# function prediction
library(caret) 
# function for factor
library(e1071)
library(SparseM)

# Stemming words

# Read csv with columns: Document , Terms and category
PathFile <- read.csv(file.choose(), sep =";", header = TRUE)
PathFilename<-read.csv(file.choose(), sep =";", header = TRUE)
#Strectur of Csv file
str(PathFile)
tail(PathFile)

# Column bind category (known classification)
#mat.df <- cbind(PathFile, PathFile$Category)
#tail(mat.df)
# Change name of new column to "category"
#colnames(mat.df)[ncol(mat.df)] <- "Category"

# Split data by rownumber into two equal portions
train <- sample(nrow(PathFile), ceiling(nrow(PathFile) * .70))
test <- (1:nrow(PathFile))[- train]

##Show Training Data
train
##Show Test Data
test
#n <- names(PathFile)
#f <- as.formula(paste("Category ~", paste(n[!n %in% "Category"], collapse = " + ")))
#f


# Isolate classifier
cl <- PathFile[, "Category"]

# Create model data and remove "category"
modeldata <- PathFile[,!colnames(PathFile) %in% "Category"]

# Create model: training set, test set, training set classifier
knn.pred <- knn(modeldata[train, ], modeldata[test, ], cl[train], 70)
knn.pred

# Confusion matrix
conf.mat <- table("Predictions" = knn.pred, Actual = cl[test])
conf.mat


ff<-predict(knn.pred,PathFilename) #here i have an error 

ct<-CrossTable(x = cl[test], y = knn.pred, prop.chisq=FALSE)

table(knn.pred,cl[test])

plot(knn.pred,
     xlab = "Number of neighbours(k)",
     main = "Comparison of Accuracy against k",
     type = "b",
     col = "black",
     lwd = 1.8,
     pch = "O")



studentModel <- train(Category ~ ., data=PathFile, method = "knn")
studentTestPred <- predict(model, test) 

# Accuracy
(accuracy <- sum(diag(conf.mat))/length(test) * 100)


# Create data frame with test data and predicted category
setwd("C:/Users/Public/Desktop/")
df.pred <- cbind(knn.pred, modeldata[test, ])
write.table(df.pred, file="output.csv", sep=";")
```

Answer (score 1):

`knn` works differently than many other classifiers. It is a "lazy" classifier. There is no model. It computes everything when you need to make a prediction. Because of that, *there is no predict method for knn*.  The `knn` function returns its predictions directly.  Since you do not provide your data, I cannot use your example, but I will illustrate with built in data using code that is a simplified version of your code.

```
library(class)
train <- sample(nrow(iris), ceiling(nrow(iris) * .70))
test <- (1:nrow(iris))[- train]
knn.pred <- knn(iris[train, 1:4], iris[test,1:4 ], iris$Species[train], 5)
knn.pred
 [1] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
 [8] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
[15] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     versicolor
[22] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
[29] versicolor versicolor versicolor virginica  versicolor versicolor versicolor
[36] versicolor virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
[43] virginica  virginica  virginica 
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

As you can see, `knn.pred` is not a model. It is the predictions for the test data.

In order to predict your new test data, you need to run knn again.

```
 knn(modeldata[train, ], PathFilename, cl[train], 70)
```

This should produce the predictions that you want.

Comment: but when i added a  new  data and  i tryed  to show the         
   confusionmatrix igot length error
Error in table(predicted_dir, actual_dir) : 
  all arguments must have the same length                                                             confusionMatrix(myknnSecond,cl[train])

Comment: How did you create `myknnSecond`?

Comment: i just made it into a new object                                                      
  myknnsecond<-knn(tdm.stack.nl[train.idx, ],PathFilename , model.cand[train.idx],k=50)

Comment: You cannot create a confusion matrix from the class of the training data `cl[train]` and the predicted class on new data. `myknnSecond`.   If you know what the classes should be for the new data `PathFilename` , use `confusionMatrix(myknnSecond, NewDataClass) `

Comment: i am using 14 textes with unkown categorys in myknnsecond . this is the script i am using  confusionMatrix(myknnSecond, (1:14)) . can u tell me what i am doing wrong here ??                                                                            ps : its working but idk if its wrong or right

Comment: If you do not have the answers, you cannot make a confusion matrix. But you _can_ get the confusion matrix for the test data if that would help you. `confusionMatrix(knn.pred, cl[test])`  I think that this should tell you the same thing as the code in your question `table(knn.pred,cl[test])`

Comment: first of all thank you veary much for your help butall argument must have the same length so it game the error that all argument must have the same length

Comment: What do you have for the lengths? `length(knn.pred)` and `length(cl[test])`

Comment: for length(knn.pred) i have 14                                                               
and  length(cl[test])  483

Comment: You must have overwritten knn.pred. Please run `knn.pred <- knn(modeldata[train, ], modeldata[test, ], cl[train], 70)` and try again.